# Getting an Azure AD JWT token for use while integrationtesting authorization

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, azure-active-directory

I have a Web API where a use-case requires one user to submit an order and another to approve it. I want to cover this feature while running my automated integration tests.

Everything I've read so far requires you to register apps and the like which shouldn't be nessasary as the API and all client are already registered and I don't want to change any of this.

I'm hoping that it's somehow possible to get the JWT token for a user only through requests to the Azure AD Web API, in order to automate the process while testing.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did this for an app, but it does require you to register an app.
We have a separate Azure AD for development/testing, so it is quite easy to make users and apps there.

What I did:

- Registered app for the integration test to use, gave it permissions to call the API in dev/test environments
- Created a couple users which I assigned to different roles on the API
- Acquired tokens in the integration test using the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow

  - Normally I would not use this flow for anything, but in this case we really do need to do a non-interactive login
- Called the API with different users and asserted the responses are as expected

If you don't want to create another app, you will have to use the keys of an existing one.
Either way, there needs to be a client app.

Comment: I would perfer not having to maintain seperate AD's. Will look into the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow for now...

Comment: Yeah, I can get that. In this case a stronger isolation was desired so that the users/apps can only access dummy data.